# QTcpSocket, wait for server

Tags: qt

I am making simple client server program using QTcpServer, QTcpSocket with out using thread,in fedora. I want to make my application, independent of sequence of what is running first, client or server.My application is running  well when I start server first, but I am not getting any way to make client wait, while server is not start and connect with serve as server start. I used waitForConnection() but it is not helping.
Please give some suggestions.

```
TcpClient::TcpClient(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::TcpClient) 

{
ui->setupUi(this);
tcpSocket= new QTcpSocket(this);
tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost,6178);     
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(sendRequest()));
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(connectionClosedByServer()));      
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this, SLOT(error())); 
.
.
..

}

void TcpClient::error() 

{ 
 ui->lStatus->setText(tcpSocket->errorString());
 closeConnection(); 
 tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost,6178);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

On the client, use`connectToHost()`. Listen to `hostFound()` or `connected()` for success, and `error()` For failure. On failure, just try to connect again (maybe after 1 to 10 seconds, using `QTimer::singleShot()`.)

This will allow the rest of your app to keep running while connection attempts are being made.

Comment: It works. If I write a connection code in error handling slot, but is it safe, or good? My code is looking like <i>TcpClient::TcpClient(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TcpClient)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    tcpSocket=  new QTcpSocket(this);tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost,6178);

Comment: connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(sendRequest()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(connectionClosedByServer()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this, SLOT(error()));
void TcpClient::error()
{
    ui->lStatus->setText(tcpSocket->errorString());
    closeConnection();
    tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost,6178);
}

Comment: @anjali: Argh. Plese don't post code in comments. It's nearly impossible to read. :) ... Anyway, I'd write a slot called `tryConnect()` which calls `connectToHost()`. I would then signal that slot, delayed via a timer, using QTimer::singleShot(), when error() is signalled (if error is such that you just want to retry').

Comment: I edited my question and wrote my code in that, my own error() slot is similar to what you saying about tryConnect(), but I wants to know, whether it is a safe practice or not.

Comment: @anjali: It's safe enough to do, but you should check the error type and see if it's a recoverable error or not (sometimes you want to inform the user... etc), and, as I said, wait a bit (0.1-5 secs) before you try to connect again (to avoid spiking the CPU or overloading the server/network).

Answer (score 0):

Simple call of connectToHost from within a slot connected to error() doesn't work for me without Qt::QueuedConnection connection option. See post by Jonas Mauricio Gastal [QTcpSocket reconnect after connection lost stay in ConnectingState](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-18082).
Sorry for my English.